# Handling multiple encodings in a single file

Tags: encoding, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm encountering some weird encoding issues. I need to parse an HTML document from the web, and I'm using the 'Content-Type' charset meta-data to determine the encoding type. 
One page has been giving me trouble and is encoded by 'Shift_jis' (Japanese) - The parser result contains some garbled characters.

When I parse the same document using UTF-8 the characters that were garbled before are parsed correctly but everything else is now garbled.

I'm assuming the document contains text in two different encoding types.

I there anyway I could parse this document correctly ?

Also, I don't how, but all the browsers seem to deal well with the issue and are presenting the page nicely.

Would really appreciate any thoughts on this.

The page that I need to parse : http://ao.recruit.co.jp/form.html

Comment: Well the charset declaration is simply lying, the page is in shift jis

Comment: 99% of the text is parsed correctly with shift jis. 1% is parsed correctly with utf-8, so both declaration are lying (and not lying).

Comment: I had no problems just using shift jis on it

Comment: I'm running this code :

URL url = new URL( "http://ao.recruit.co.jp/form.html");

String string = IOUtils.toString(url.openStream(), "Shift_jis");

The tag "<a href="http://www.recruit-mp.co.jp/company/data/" target="_blank" class="company">" is followed by garbled text.

Comment: I have `莨夂､ｾ讎りｦ?` after that tag, when decoding as shift jis

Comment: ',' at the middle and '?' at the end, for example, is not part of the text. Look for the link in the browser and you'll see something different.

Comment: All I see in the browser is `莨夂､ｾ讎りｦ`, exactly the same as the result of using `'//IGNORE'` (PHP with iconv) in my code would give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what the browser sees is:

```
莨夂､ｾ讎りｦ
```

What is shown in rendered html is not the same because of the CSS `text-indent: -9999px` and the [background image laid over it](http://ao.recruit.co.jp/img/nav/company.png). But it's there. [Removing them will show the text browser is seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbEz2.png).

Out of the box, decoding as Shift-Jis should give you `莨夂､ｾ讎りｦ?`, but if you want same results as in a browser, you should use a custom `CharsetDecoder` with `IGNORE`:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://ao.recruit.co.jp/form.html");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("Shift-Jis").newDecoder();

decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);

Reader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(bis, decoder);

String result = IOUtils.toString(inputReader);
System.out.print(result);
```

This will give you same result as with browsers. Of course, it won't parse the text from the image file.